# Why is this inside an object window?

Tags: javascript, this

Consider the following code:

```
var obj = {
    x: this
}
```

`obj.x` turns out to be `window`. I thought `this` would refer to `obj`.

I don't understand how `this` works in the above situation. Even with late binding such as in JavaScript, shouldn't `x` refer to the `obj` object? I understand all other cases for `this` where its value is determined by how it is called in the code. Can someone please help me understand this behavior of `this`?

Comment: `this` refers to current context. It can point to instance if its method is called or to function scope in class and as default in non strict mode, it points to window (*indefined in strict*)

Comment: As far as I know this is bound at call time in JS. Then should the value for this should not be bound when I actually call obj.x ?

Comment: `this` refers to the current execution context, and is bound every time a new execution context is established. An execution context is established when you enter eval code or function code. That means your code is still in the default execution context (as there's no function or eval code where a new context would be established), which is the global execution context, where `this` refers to window (outside of strict mode).

Comment: Considering your code looks like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/hpnm5ert/), what should be the context or this over here?

Answer (score 0):

`window` is the default value for `this` if you run your code in a browser. As noted in the comments below, `this` will be undefined if `'use strict';` is in effect.

the value of `this` changes on the basis of the object where it resides.

example:

## 1

```
var test = {
  a: 1,
  b: function () {
    console.log(this.a)
  }
}
```

In this case the value of `this` will be the containing object.

```
var test = {
  a: 1,
  b: function () {
    setTimeout(function () {console.log('surprise', this.a)}, 0)
  }
}
```

This piece of code however doesn't give the same result.
Here without strict mode on, on a browser, property `a` will be accessed over the `window`.

The reason being the function in the setTimeout doesn't have the access to the object.

## 2

```
var someObject = {
  value: 1,
  someFunction () {
    return function () {
      console.log(this.value)
    }
  }
}

var displayValue = someObject.someFunction()
displayValue()
```

In this case too, `this` is undefined, as the value of `this` changes with respect to the object which contains the function being called.

`someFunction` is a method on the object `someObject` therefore, the value of `this` inside would be equal to `someObject` but the function returned by `someFunction` is not called by `someObject` hence the difference.

Comment: Really vague and sometimes wrong, if you're in strict mode or an environment that doesn't support window or the BOM.

Comment: This should have been a comment but considering you do not have enough reps, I'd suggest either remove it or make it descriptive enough to suffice for the term *answer*

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `window` does not even exist in some JavaScript environments (e.g. Node).

Comment: I'll edit my answer @AndrewLi

Comment: As far as I know this is bound at call time in JS. Then should the value for this should not be bound when I actually call obj.x ?

Comment: Adding to @Marty's comment, `this` is set to `undefined` in strict mode.

Comment: @AndrewLi please check the updated answer.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question though...

Comment: @AndrewLi The question head got changed now. My answer contains the working of `this` as asked in the question?

Comment: @ankitgupta No, you never explain why the value is this when in a property. Nothing is invoked, and you don't mention the execution context

Answer (score 0):

This refers to Current Execution Context which in this case (which is initial) is `window` object.

[Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work#answer-3127440)

---

### More Specific to this question

One important principal about `this` is that:

> `this` is not assigned a value until an **object invokes the function where this is defined**. Let’s call the function where this is defined the *“this Function.”*

So, lets assume you've defined your object this way:

```
 var person = {
    firstName   :"John",
    lastName    :"Doe",
    showHometown:function () {
        console.log (this);
    }
 }
```

Since the `this` keyword is used inside the `showHometown` method, and the showHometown method is defined on the person object,​ `this` will have the value of the `person` object because the `person` object will invoke `showHometown()`​.

As you see difference between `x` in your defined object & mine, **is who invokes them** which is formally referred to *Current Execution Context*.

Comment: But you never answer the question? You're talking about methods while the user is talking  about a property and value...

Comment: @AndrewLi I'm talking about context, not method. main method to change context/scope in js is by functions, its why I 'm trying to explain it by functions. Both object definitions are talking about `this` value

Comment: This answer is just like the other one, it does not address the user's question. Your first sentence is correct but really vague. Expand on that instead.